# Is there any way to record video with AVCaptureMovieFileOutput and change cameras?

Tags: ios, video, camera, avfoundation

I want to record a video with `AVFoundation` and `AVCaptureSession` using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`.

I want to record a video like Instagram Stories, so I want to change the camera while the video is recording. The problem with `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` is that when I change the `captureDevice` in the `captureSession` the delegate method `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` sends an error with the text **Recording stopped** and everything stops.

I've thought about stopping the front camera video before I change the camera, and save it, then save the back camera video and join them in the same video. Is this a good option? Or Should I use `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` to achieve this?

Comment: I had a similar challenge a few years ago. I saw no way but to use multiple video files (due to size issues, lags...) so I started first with `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` which proved OK for all but the audio which annoyingly glitched when stitched. I found no way of removing this glitch so I had do manual recording with injection of `CMSampleBuffer` chunks manually and separately for audio and video. I hope you find a quicker solution but do note you might have greater trouble with audio then video and audio glitch is really nasty in mid conversation.